# C# create array from another array

Tags: c#, arrays

Hopefully its a really simple solution to this. I've got a string that I've split by "-" which I then want to split into another array but can't seem to get it to work. Any help appreciated.

```
SplitEC = textBox1.Text.Split('-');
```

e.g. `textBox1.text = "asdf-asfr"`

I can then get:

```
SplitEC[0]
```

e.g. `asdf`

I then want to get each individual element of `SplitEC[0]` but for the life of me nothing works.

e.g. `SplitEC[2]` would be `d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply chain the array indexers. `SplitEC[0]` returns a string.. which implements the indexer for individual `char`s..

```
char c = SplitEc[0][2]; // d
//       |________||__|
//        ^ string  ^  characters of the string
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `SplitEC[0]` is a `string`, you could just access the characters individually like this:

```
char c = SplitEC[0][2];                // 'd'
```

Note that the result is a `char`; if you want a `string` just call `ToString()`:

```
string c = SplitEC[0][2].ToString();   // "d"
```

Or if you want an array of chars, you can call `ToCharArray`:

```
char[] chars = SplitEC[0].ToCharArray();
char c = char[2];                      // 'd'
```

Or if you want an array of strings, you can use a little linq:

```
string[] charStrings = SplitEC[0].Select(Char.ToString).ToArray();
string c = charStrings[2];             // "d"
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If there is anything incorrect or unclear in my answer I'd glad to correct.

Comment: Unfortunate.. your answer has more detail and you also received a downvote. +1 to undo the stupid downvote.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead +1 to you too. I think you beat me by a few seconds anyway. :)